# Slim framework's REST API not working in 000webhost(free web hosting server)

Tags: php, json, web-hosting, slim

I created an api using SLIM framework. I hosted that in 000webhost.com. when i tried to access the api using REST client the server is redirecting it to http://error404.000webhost.com/? . but response code is 200 ok. I tried a lot whole day and i couldnt solve it. I even tried to modify htaccess file but couldnt help. please some one help me.
my htaccess file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Did you try with the `.htaccess` provided by Slim?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `000webhost.com` has an old version of php that does not support slim.